# How do I reset a box to its original format in jQuery with a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a reset button that resets all the elements that I have changed to this box on my page with buttons. I have everything figured out except how to reset the box to its original format. I am not allowed to use a CSS file. I don't know what comes after the last $("#box"). Here is my HTML code:

```js
function index() {
  var $box = $('#box');
  $("#button1").click(function() {
    $("#box").animate({
      height: '300px'
    });
  });
  $("#button2").click(function() {
    $("#box").css("background-color", "blue");
  });
  $("#button3").click(function() {
    $("#box").fadeOut();
  });
  $("#button4").click(function() {
    $("#box").
  });
};

$(document).ready(index);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>

<div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>

<button id="button1">Grow</button>
<button id="button2">Blue</button>
<button id="button3">Fade</button>
<button id="button4">Reset</button>
```

Comment: *I am not allowed to use a CSS file.* - Is this homework?

Comment: You could try having a second box with the default format and then just replace `#box` with that element.

Comment: Try removing the `style` attribute, assuming you are not using styles that should remove all added styles.

Comment: It is pre-work for a bootcamp I am taking.  If I don't get everything correct then I just turn in what I have, this is just to learn before we start the bootcamp.

Comment: The original format is right there in the `style` attribute of the `<div>`. Just apply that using the `.css()` command.

Comment: Is there a difference between this question and the one you asked a few hours ago? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45982509/using-javascript-and-jquery-for-the-first-time

Answer (score 0):

You can use `style` tag if a separate css file is not allowed.Also the `animate` function will add the property to style attribute, & on resetting you need to remove/reset those property

```js
function index() {
  var $box = $('#box');
  $("#button1").click(function() {
    $("#box").animate({
      height: '300px'
    });
  });
  $("#button2").click(function() {
    $("#box").css("background-color", "blue");
  });
  $("#button3").click(function() {
    $("#box").fadeOut();
  });
  $("#button4").click(function() {
    $("#box").removeAttr('style')
  });
};

$(document).ready(index);
```

```css
.boxStyle {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 25px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>
<div id="box" class="boxStyle"></div>
<button id="button1">Grow</button>
<button id="button2">Blue</button>
<button id="button3">Fade</button>
<button id="button4">Reset</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .clone method and use replaceWith to restore it as in below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var boxClone = $('#box').clone();
     $("#button1").click(function() {
     $("#box").animate({
         height: '300px'
     });
 });

 $("#button2").click(function() {
     $("#box").css("background-color", "blue");
 });

 $("#button3").click(function() {
     $("#box").fadeOut();
 });

 $("#button4").click(function() {
     $("#box").replaceWith(boxClone.clone());
 });
});
```